# Memoization: can the arguments be used as key in the cache object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, memoization

I have this solution for a memoization function.

```js
const slice = Array.prototype.slice
function memoize(fn){
    const cache = {}
    return (...args) => {
        const params = slice.call(args)
        console.log(params)
        if(cache[params]){
            console.log('cached')
            return cache[params]
        } else{
            let result = fn(...args)
            cache[params] = result
            console.log('not cached')
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

`cache[params]` is the point. `cache` is an object and `params` is an array. Will this always work? After some researching I am still not confident this code is correct.

Comment: Object keys have to be string. You can convert the array to string and use it as key

Comment: It's not my solution but I've found it in one guide. I'm new in Js and I can't understand is it author's mistake or my misunderstandig of some concept

Comment: It is not really possible to do this. The arguments may be objects, and those objects may have nested objects, which may even have circular references. Objects can be mutable. Creating a "hash" for such arguments needs several assumptions for it to work reliably.

Comment: The memoize concept uses stringified arrays/objects as a key. If you specifically want to use an array as a key, you can use [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but it's not suitable for memoizes.

Comment: Then there is also the question ... What is more expensive, hashing an object or (re)calculating the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such memoization can work for very simple cases, but it does not work in many other cases, for instance when:

- the arguments are objects. They will often stringify to "[object Object]", and so different objects are treated as if they are the same.
- the arguments are strings but cannot be distinguished because of the poor way they are separated when the arguments array is stringified (comma delimiter)

Some demos of failures:

1. Arguments are Objects

```js
const slice = Array.prototype.slice

function memoize(fn){
    const cache = {}
    return (...args) => {
        const params = slice.call(args)
        if(cache[params]){
            return cache[params]
        } else{
            let result = fn(...args)
            cache[params] = result
            return result
        }
    }
}

// The function we will test with:
function sum(a) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let value of a) total += value;
    return total;
}

function test() {
    console.log(sum(new Set([1,2,3]))); // should be 6
    console.log(sum(new Set([2,4,6]))); // should be 12
}

console.log("Run test without memoization...");
test(); // Perform test without memoization
sum = memoize(sum); // Memoize the function
console.log("Run test WITH memoization...");
test(); // Test again, but now with memoization
```

2. Arguments are strings that have commas:

```js
const slice = Array.prototype.slice

function memoize(fn){
    const cache = {}
    return (...args) => {
        const params = slice.call(args)
        if(cache[params]){
            return cache[params]
        } else{
            let result = fn(...args)
            cache[params] = result
            return result
        }
    }
}

// The function we will test with:
function compareString(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b); // returns -1, 0 or 1.
}

function test() {
    console.log(compareString("b,a", "c")); // should be -1
    // Change the arguments such that the concatenation with comma remains the same
    console.log(compareString("b", "a,c")); // should be  1
}

console.log("Run test without memoization...");
test(); // Perform test without memoization
compareString = memoize(compareString); // Memoize the function
console.log("Run test WITH memoization...");
test(); // Test again, but now with memoization
```

#### Other remarks on the code

- Calling `slice` is useless, as `args` is already a new array.
- `if(cache[params])` will evaluate to `false` when the already cached value is a falsy value, like 0, "", false. Doing `if (params in cache)` would avoid that issue
- `params` will be stringified, which (as shown above) is not guaranteed to uniquely identify an array of arguments.

#### Improvement

If we can require that the arguments passed to our function are *immutable*, then we can use these immutable values or references as keys in a `Map`.
This Map would become a tree of Maps when there are multiple arguments, so that when a lookup is made for the first argument in the main Map, it returns a nested Map, and then in that Map the next argument would be used as key, ...etc, until the deep Map is found for the last argument. In that final Map, a reserved key is used to retrieve the cached value. This reserved key can be Symbol that is only known by the `memoize` function, so that it can never collide with an argument value.

Disclaimer: This will not work when objects can mutate between calls.

Here is how that looks:

```js
function memoize(fn){
    const end = Symbol("end"); // A unique reference, only known here
    const cache = new Map;
    return (...args) => {
        let node = args.reduce((node, arg) => {
             if (!node.has(arg)) node.set(arg, new Map);
             return node.get(arg);
        }, cache);
        if (!node.has(end)) node.set(end, fn(...args));
        return node.get(end);
    }
}

// The function we will test with:
let numCalls = 0;
function length(a) { // Length of a linked list
    numCalls++; // Keep track of the number of calls made
    return a ? length(a.next) + 1 : 0;
}

function test() {
    numCalls = 0; // Reset the number of calls
    let head = { next: { next: { next: {}}}}; // Linked list with 4 nodes
    console.log(length(head)); // should be 4
    // Now exclude the head node:
    console.log(length(head.next)); // should be 3
    console.log("number of calls: ", numCalls); 
}

console.log("Run test without memoization...");
test(); // Perform test without memoization
length = memoize(length); // Memoize the function
console.log("Run test WITH memoization...");
test(); // Test again, but now with memoization
```

Again, this cannot be used when objects mutate between calls. But for all other scenarios it should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Object keys are supposed to be string/symbols.
Depending on how you input array affects the output, you can [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array and use it as your cache key:

```
const slice = Array.prototype.slice
function memoize(fn){
    const cache = {}
    return (...args) => {
        const params = slice.call(args)
        let paramsString = params.sort().join('');
        console.log(paramsString)
        if(cache[paramsString]){
            console.log('cached')
            return cache[paramsString]
        } else{
            let result = fn(...args)
            cache[paramsString] = result
            console.log('not cached')
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

If the order does not matter then you can `.sort()`. If order is important then you can remove the sort and just join. This is not perfect but works for simple cases.

Comment: Simply calling `join('')` will screw you over more sooner than later. You should definitely provide a separator to be inserted. Example: `[12, 34]` vs. `[1, 234]`. In your case both will result in a key `1234`, sorting or not.